# Onclick switch from one to two images then back to one

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick, image

Trying to figure out how to switch from one to two images then back to one with an onlick.

So far I have below which works no problem for switching to one image and back to original image.  Ultimately I'm trying to get the first onclick event to be two images vertically and then click again back to the first single image.

```
var play = false;
    function toggle() {
        var image = document.getElementById('image')
        var scan = document.getElementById('scan');
        play = !play;
        if (play) {
            image.src = "pause.png";image.width="182";image.height="182";image.border="0";
            scan.play();
        }
        else {
            image.src = "play.png";image.width="182";image.height="182";image.border="0";   
            scan.pause();
        }
    }
```

and in body:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"><img onclick="toggle()" id="image" src="play.png" alt="image" width="182" height="182" style="margin:auto; position:absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; border: 0;"></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work fine except, take out the width, height and border from the javascript, they're not changing so why have it there and risk some browsers freaking out on them?

I just put this together real quick to test and it works a treat.. I've commented out scan.play and pause of course but I'm assuming you've checked the console in your browser to see if those are throwing any errors?

I took the `<a>` out and used style `cursor=pointer` instead for the click-able element as well.. either way works but this is neater and works from ie6 I think, ie7+ definately.

`edit: removed source block didn't achieve goal of question`

After discussion in comment there's heaps of ways to do it, and I'd probably use jQuery but since you're not here's one not

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var play = true;
        function toggle() {
            //var scan = document.getElementById('scan');
            var playpause = document.getElementById('playpause');
            var btnplay = playpause.getElementsByClassName('play');
            var btnpause = playpause.getElementsByClassName('pause');
            play = !play;
            if (play) {
                btnplay[0].className = 'btn play active';
                btnpause[0].className = 'btn pause';
                //scan.play();
            }
            else {
                btnplay[0].className = 'btn play';
                btnpause[0].className = 'btn pause active';
                //scan.pause();
            }
        }
    </script>

    <style>
        .btn {
            width: 182px;
            height: 182px;
            cursor: pointer;
            position: absolute;
            visibility: hidden;
        }
        .btn.active { visibility: visible; }
        .btn.play { background: url('play.png') no-repeat 0 0; }
        .btn.pause { 
            background: url('pause.png') no-repeat 0 0;
            padding: 182px 0 0 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="playpause">
        <div class="btn play active" onclick="toggle()">
        </div>
        <div class="btn pause" onclick="toggle()">
            <img src="other.png" alt="other" />
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not getting any errors with the code I posted as it works as expected, switching one image for another on an onclick.  The scan is for an if audio id (play) tag is in play.  I'm trying to get it to give two images to display onclick (eg. pause.png + another.png) and then next onclick back to just the single play.png.

Comment: ok cool...  there's a couple of ways to do this but I'll update my answer to show a quick and easy way to have the images preloaded and you can even later add effects

Comment: Thanks for the cursor=pointer style tip.  I'm new to this and was looking for a way to get rid of the "javascript:void(0)" showing in the status bar and this did the trick.

Comment: Ok check the reply now, here's one of many ways..  with the additional image you could do what I have where it's just inside the button div, though that makes it also click-able which I'm not sure if you want that.   If you're not using jQuery I found myself wishing I had it even for this for what that's worth... makes everything easy

Comment: Thanks so much.  This is what I was looking for.  I'm new to this and perhaps sometime soon I'll check out using jQuery.  Glad you could help.